# Why is my array not growing?

Tags: arrays, for-loop, go, slice

I am trying to generate numbers that are factors of 3 || 5  in an array.

Here is a copy of my code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    i := 0

    for i < 1000 {
        var nums []int

        if i%3 == 0 || i%5 == 0 {
            nums := append(nums, i)
            fmt.Println(nums)
        }

        i++

    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this isnt going as planned as it appears to by over writing the value at nums[0]. Here a the last few values of my terminal output.

```
[981]
[984]
[985]
[987]
[990]
[993]
[995]
[996]
[999]
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Also tried this:

```
var nums []int // initialize the slice outside for loop
for i < 1000 {
    if i%3 == 0 || i%5 == 0 {
        nums = append(nums, i) // append to the slice outside loop not create a new one using short variable declaration
        fmt.Println(nums)
    }
    i++
}
```

But got Same result

Comment: You've declared the array inside the loop. Therefore you're re-declaring it each iteration. Declare it outside of the for loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you are creating a new variable of `[]int` slice rather than appending to the created one outside if condition. Create the `[]int` slice outside for loop and don't create a new variable using short declaration inside if condition.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    i := 0
    var nums []int
    for i < 1000 {
        if i%3 == 0 || i%5 == 0 {
            nums = append(nums, i)
        }
        i++
    }
    fmt.Println(nums)
    fmt.Println(len(nums), cap(nums)) // check for length and capacity of slice to know the size of slice after appending all data
}
```

Working Code on [Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/5OJLH9Knwzn)

Comment: Thanks for this Tried it in the play ground doesnt work. Originally had it like this, but put it in the loop out of desperation / trial and error

Comment: it gives me the same output

Comment: @Data_Kid check the link inside my answer. I have tried on go playground.

Comment: Then I must be clicking the wrong link. Mine its not an array of numbers. Its the same output as I have in my terminal i.e `[0],[3],[5],[9]........[999]`. what I want to `[0,3,5,9....999]`

Comment: @Data_Kid Check the answer again in the link. It is working now you are printing the slice inside the for loop. I have edited my answer

Comment: [Link to optimal working example](https://play.golang.org/p/L81kt-rmU87)

Comment: the link you added initially was my dodgy code. Thanks its been a very good thought exercise. The problem was where I was printing the value

Comment: @Data_Kid The problem was included in my answer. The slice you are creating is new everytime you loop through the code. This was wrong so if you print the len and capacity of the slice you will surely know. Always check the length and capacity of slice when you are increasing its size